# No such column 'Comments' on entity 'Case'

Tags: soql, case

I tried querying `Comments` field(Internal Comments standard field) on `Case` object which should be a pretty straightforward job. But I received above error while all the FLS and all are fine. I checked the WSDL and realized that the field is not there even we can see the field in the object setup.

Can anyone explain why is this? Can't we use `Comments` field on queries? For formula field builder also it's not showing up.

Comment: CaseComments is a child object of Case. You need to do a inner join or additional query to retrieve it. Refer this [post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34816/soql-for-getting-casecoment-for-a-case)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comments not a "real" field, but instead a "magic" field that allows a user to enter case comments while editing a case record, when placed on a page layout. There are several fields like this, including Lead's Campaign field. You can't query on it, but you can query the CaseComment child object instead:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM CaseComments) FROM Case
```

Comment: Hmm, is the existence of this field actually documented anywhere? Interesting. I don't see it in the schema either.

Comment: @AdrianLarson As far as I can tell: no. It's been around since at least 2005 (my earliest experience with SFDC), but I've never seen it documented. It does not appear in any API (SOAP, REST, Bulk, etc), but it exists in Setup > Customize > Cases > Fields, where it's defined as Text(4000), and you can add it to the page layout to allow users to add comments while editing the case. This is something you'd probably never know about unless you played with the system.

Comment: So it does. Weird that it can't even be described.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Welcome to the wild and crazy world of salesforce's weird "magic" fields. Off the top of my head, I think there's literally only two of these fields, neither of which are documented, can't be described, can't be accessed by any API, etc. I'd love to be proven wrong, though. I would think that these fields have a special place in the documentation somewhere, considering the thousands of pages the documents contain.

Comment: Thanks, as you mentioned I got confused why it's not there as it's in the setup. Also referred to docs with no luck at all. Added to layout the field but it's not there as a field. errrr! Ok I'll go for it as per the answer.

Answer (score 4):

That field sure [isn't documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_case.htm). Perhaps you mean to query for the `CaseComments`?

```
SELECT (SELECT CommentBody FROM CaseComments) FROM Case
```